# Scheduling function call

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have function ,

```
-(void)serverFetch{
  //server fetch
}
```

In every 15mintutes, i'm calling this method using NSTimer,

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:900.0f repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {


    [self fetchFromServer];


}];
```

I'm using APNS in my app, so when we receive the notification , again i'm calling this method.
So Scheduler thread and this notification thread should not happen in parallel.  For instance, when scheduler thread is in operation and push notification arrives then push notification thread should wait for scheduler thread.How can i achieve this?Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) (GCD). Create a *serial queue* and add blocks to it for asynchronous execution when your timer fires or notifications arrive, the blocks will be executed strictly one after the other. This will only work correct if the work each block does is completely synchronous, that is when the block returns all its work is complete.

If your blocks contain asynchronous work then you will also need a *semaphore*. A block should acquire the semaphore when it starts execution and its final asynchronous action should release it. In this way though the block scheduled by the serial queue returns and the queue starts the next block that next block will immediately block waiting to acquire the semaphore until the previous block's last asynchronous action releases it.

If after studying GCD, designing a solution, and implementing it you have a problem ask a new question, show the code you have written, and explain the problem. Someone will undoubtedly help you move forward.

HTH